# Ag-grid-angular row group tree data slow rendering

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using `Ag-grid-angular` row grouping using tree data.  I am having very large data set of around ten thousand rows or more. I have created a `drop-down` where I have levels as an option. When I select the level all grid groups are `expanded/collapsed` accordingly at once. I am getting the slowness and page freeze problem when I am collapsing or expanding.

**Expand/collapse method:**

```
expandGrid(level){
this.selectedOption = level.toString();
If(level === 1) {
this.gridapi.collapseAll();
} else {
this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) =>{
if (node.level <= level - 2) {
 node.setExpanded(true);}
else {
node.setExpanded(false);
}
});
}}
```

Comment: I added a complete answer to solve your slowness problem. My solution collapses and expands the nodes all at once NOT one by one unlike the example in your question. I added several different examples for specific reasons. Please check my answer. If it solves, please confirm it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have a complete solution especially for those who have concern about latency and slowness.

Please [see this example that I created](https://plnkr.co/edit/J4mQ5aKdGxgFlPkd) on Plnkr.

Basically you can use the following code blocks **to expand and collapse** the tree data on the grid:

*At first, imports, definitions and assignments:*

```
import { GridApi } from 'ag-grid-community';
```

then:

```
gridApi!: GridApi; // variable

constructor() {}

onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  // other codes...
}


expand() {
  this.gridApi.expandAll();
}

collapse() {
  this.gridApi.collapseAll();
}
```

However if you want to collapse and expand a specific node level groups, you can use the following examples:

```
collapse2ndLevel() {
  this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.level === 1) {
      node.setExpanded(false);
    }
  });
}

expand2ndLevel() {
  this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.level < 2 && node.isExpandable) {
      node.setExpanded(true);
    }
  });
}

collapse3rdLevel() {
  this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.level === 2 && node.isExpandable) {
      node.setExpanded(false);
    }
  });
}

expand3rdLevel() {
  this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.level < 3 && node.isExpandable) {
      node.setExpanded(true);
    }
  });
}
```

Please [check out this example that I created](https://plnkr.co/edit/J4mQ5aKdGxgFlPkd) o Plnkr.